# Why does Outlook 2013 say I have 3 Reminders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Near the bottom, lefthand corner of Outlook, it says that I have 3 Reminders, like this:

[image]

However, I don't have any outstanding reminders.  In fact, when I click on the "Reminders: 3" display, it opens my Reminders window, and that window is free of any reminders, like this picture below.  Any idea why Outlook 2013 behaves this way?

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug in Outlook; you should probably seek chat support from Microsoft Support or ask on Microsoft Answers.

Comment: What kind of mail account(s) are setup in Outlook?

Comment: This is a Microsoft Exchange account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, close outlook and do the following:

- Press Windows Key + R (Or go to the start search area)
- Type this in:
  `outlook.exe /cleanreminders`
- Press Enter

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: That helps, but it's a temporary Band-Aid.  The problem resurfaces later that day, or by morning the next day.

Comment: There is no fix for this.  I just run this command any time I think about it, and it temporarily fixes the problem for a few days.

Comment: I actually had this happen the other day, and I simply exited Outlook and restarted it (without the /cleanreminders param) and it went away.

Answer (score 2):

Could you clarify what server you are using?  Is it exchange?

Sounds like something is corrupt inside in one of your message stores.

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/delete-reminders-that-keep-returning/

You could try MFCMAPI to look inside and see what is going on:

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/delete-reminders-that-keep-returning/#mfcmapi

You might be able to use that tool to trace it back to events that are causing the problem, and then delete those events.

Comment: Yes, it's an Exchange account.  The MFCAPI app shows me all of my ongoing reminders, but I still don't know how to track down the culprit; I don't want to just delete all of my ongoing meetings.  If I wanted to do that, I would just delete them in Outlook.

Comment: (Bounty awarded for effort)

Comment: Maybe on a one-by-one basis start recreating the meetings.

Comment: Could try Scanpst  http://www.msoutlook.info/question/77 ... maybe your OST file is corrupt?  Have you checked your tasklist?